# My Laptop wont shut down or restart, Help anyone?

Tags: shutdown

I installed Linux Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (Finnish Remix) on my laptop but now the problem is that Laptop wont shut down or restart normally. Screen just go black but the PC is still on.

Here is my Laptop Specs:

Model: HP Pavilion X360 11.6"

CPU: Intel Pentium N3540 2.16 Ghz Quad Core (2.66 Ghz Turbo clock)

GPU: Intel HD Graphics (1.7Gb maximum Shared memory)

RAM: 4Gb DDR3 1600Mhz

Storage: 500Gb SSHD

Laptop had Pre-Installed Windows 8.1, 64 bit

Sorry if my english is bad.

I dont have any Experience on Linux enviroment. I bought this laptop for its lightweight and portability. I just wanted to try A Linux now that i have the time Learn about Linux in general on my freetime.

So i hope easy steps on how to make Shutdowns and restarts working as they should. Thanks :D

Comment: Do you did something with this?

Comment: I decided to make a fresh install in my case

Answer (score 0):

It's not a definitve solution, but it works whenever this happens:

On command line `sudo init 6` to restart and `sudo init 0` to shutdown

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Open the console with pressing the "Ctrl" + "t"
In the console write this code:

```
sudo reboot now!
```

then enter your password, with this code you should reboot your system, 
or you can shutdown with:

```
sudo shutdown now
```

If the console not open with "Ctrl" + "t", you can open a "tty" with "ctrl"+"alt"+"F1"

Hope this will help you.